# jQuery - resetting a variable

Tags: jquery, variables, null, undefined, reset

I have a variable in a web page that gets set to a value and is of type string.  When a button is clicked, it calls a function & at the end of the function, I would want to clean up anything that had been set previously.  I have tried using:

```
$.removeData(myVar);
```

but it doesn't do anything.   Log statements before & after that statement show that it still has the value & type both before & after the above statement.

Another unused variable has a value of `undefined` and a type of `undefined`.  Both these variables happen to be global variables in the page.

How do you reset `myVar` to its initial state?  I know it ought to be simple, but I'm missing something.  Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Instead of using global variable, use local one inside function

Comment: better you show some code or jsfiddle

Comment: @pm.calabrese Not all programming questions require code. He's described the basic problem fairly well.

Comment: @Katana314 i did not say is required, i said would be better. And in anycase is trying to describe something that is actually code... so why not show the code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well...several possible direct answers.

```
myVar = undefined;
myVar = null;
delete window.myVar;
```

HOWEVER, I would question the logic of having the variable be global, but only be used in certain methods. Here's how it might be better to structure (with a random pseudo-example of adding up values from ajax):

```
addAjaxButton.onClick(function() {
  var counter = 0;
  ajax(function(addition) {
    counter += addition;
    ajax(function(moreAdd) {
      counter += moreAdd;
      alert('Total is ' + counter);
    });
  });
});
```

In that case, counter doesn't need to be deleted - it will just go out of scope when all AJAX is complete.

Answer (score 2):

Just assign a value to it. If the initial state was undefined, set it to null. You don't have to do anything fancy with jQuery to kill the value.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your function is doing some "side effecty" things and you want to undo those things?

This statement

> I would want to clean up anything that had been set previously.

Is not the same as this statement

> How do you reset myVar to its initial state?

What you actually want to do is copy it to a locally scoped variable and not change the global. This code demonstrates using function parameters and making a copy of the global var locally.

```
var someGlobal = 1;
someMethod();
someOtherMethod(someGlobal);

function someMethod() {
  var localVar = someGlobal;
  localVar = 2;
}

function someOtherMethod(localVar) {
  localVar = 3;
}

window.console.log(someGlobal);
```

Answer (score -1):

This would be a way to reset the value:

```
$(myVar).val('');
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Sorry that you didn't like the phrasing of my answer.  I have edited it to seem less like a question for clarification and be clearer as a suggested answer.